# Finding distinct pairs and their product in python

Tags: python

I am learning python and I don't expect an answer. I just need assistance really.

I'm given multiple lists that from the lists I need to check to make sure that:

a) It is not an empty list

b) It has more than one integer within the list

c) Check if the integers within the list has an even product value or an odd product value by checking for distinct pairs. For example `list1 = [1,2,3]`. This would return False because the product is even. `list2 = [3,2,3]` would return True because the product of the two odd pairs is odd.

These are some of my ideas:

a) To check if it is an empty list you would type:

```
if not myList: 
    return(False)
```

or

```
if myList != []: 
    return(True)
```

b)

```
if myList != 1: 
    return(True)
```

or

```
if int in myList < 0 and if int in myList > 2: 
    return(False)
```

c)

```
if len(myList) % 2 == 0: 
    return(False)
```

Because if there are two even doubles then it would return even either way. I just want to find the odd product.

```
   if len(myList) % 2 != 0:
       for i in myList:
          if i % i == 1:
              return(True)
          else:
              return(False)
```

I should test this out but I actually just came up with it writing this. Finding the pairs is pretty difficult.

I figured that if the end result is 1 then they are the same number- right? First time user of this site so I am not familiar with the standard protocol of questions (I did read the rules though).

Sorry if this is long and thanks to whoever helps me out!

Comment: One should that the most idiomatic and "pythonic" of all the options you showed above is `if not lst`.

Comment: `because the product of the two odd pairs is odd` I don't quite understand the logic required here!

Comment: I also don't understand c). Are you referring to checking if the product of every integer in the list is even or odd?

Comment: While you are learning python, try to use [snake_case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) instead of [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) in your programs.

Comment: Please clarify the problem for part c, as well as your logic.  Your Python use is not strong enough that your code can speak for itself.  For instance, **i % i** is always 0: any number divides itself evenly.  You also seem to confuse a list with its contents: myList is not the same as myList[0].

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The problem itself confuses me a bit as well. "Write a short Python function called contains_odd_product that takes a sequence of integer values and determines if there is a distinct pair of numbers in the sequence whose product (multiplication of the two elements in the pair) is odd." Is the problem. Again, thank you for all of your help.

Answer (score 1):

> a) It is not an empty list

Your empty container check seems fine (just drop the parentheses)

```
if not myList: 
    return False
```

> b) It has more than one integer within the list

This doesn't work, it's a number check not a list length check:

```
if myList != 1: 
    return(True)
```

you may instead want (which also takes care of case 'a'):

```
if len(myList) < 2:
    return False
```

> c) Check if the integers within the list has an even product value or
>   an odd product value by checking for distinct pairs.

This one is tricky as your explanation seems inconsistent with your examples:

> For example list1 = [1,2,3]. This would return False because the
>   product is even. list2 = [3,2,3] would return True because the product
>   of the two odd pairs is odd.

Both lists have an even product but you return `True` for one and `False` for the other.

Your subsequent explanation seems to imply you want to determine parity without multiplying by noting that all odd elements = odd product (True) and any even element = even product (False) which leads to two possible predicates:

```
def are_all_odd(myList):  # odd product True; even product False
    return all(element % 2 for element in myList)

def is_any_even(myList):  # even product True; odd product False
    return any(element % 2 == 0 for element in myList)
```

But the modulus operator `%` is division which is as expensive as multiplication.  To avoid that we can do this bit-wise:

```
def are_all_odd(myList):  # odd product True; even product False
    return all(element & 1 for element in myList)

def is_any_even(myList):  # even product True; odd product False
    return any(~element & 1 for element in myList)
```

Using generators as input to `any()` and `all()` means these will stop as soon as the answer can be determined.  However, the data may not be in the optimal order to minimize the number of tests.